# How to write a text file from a webserver to an Azure Fileshare?

Tags: javascript, php, azure, cors

We currently have a webpage that on submit of a form uses PHP and creates a text file onto a webserver. We want to write this text file to an Azure File Share (not a blob) so we can access it from a VM. How do we go about doing this, we have tried using HTTPS POST requests and have hit a wall with CORS and now we are lost.

```
    function sendFile(){
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("PUT","https://sofyvhdfiles.file.core.windows.net/sofyvhd/test.txt",false);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Authentication", "SharedKey myaccount:[Key Here]");
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("x-ms-version","2017-04-17");
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("x-ms-content-length",102400);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("x-ms-type","text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
        xhttp.send();
        var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
        console.log(response);
    }

    sendFile();
```

Comment: Can you add relevant code that you've tried so far?

Comment: I added the function we've been working with. We run it and get errors with the preflight response not having an "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header.

Comment: Not sure if/how you would add CORS support to an azure file share, but you can certainly send the request via PHP. If you are creating the file with Javascript, you could POST it to your PHP webserver and let PHP do the PUT operation. For example, you can use http://phphttpclient.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set CORS rules for file storage service using the [Azure portal](http://portal.azure.com).

[image]
[image]

---

### Update:

Thanks for Gaurav's reminding in the comment. As you are using Javascript, it's better to use SAS (Shared Access Signature) to create a file. SAS is much easier and more secure to use than SharedKey in front-end. You can follow the steps below to do that.

1. Generate SAS from the Azure portal and copy the `SAS token`:

[image]

2. Call `https://sofyvhdfiles.file.core.windows.net/sofyvhd/test.txt` + `SAS token` using HTTPS PUT with `x-ms-type` and `x-ms-content-length`:

[image]

Comment: That should do the trick, I'll check it out tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: Nour El-Din Ayad - Unfortunately it won't. Not that the answer provided by Aaron is incorrect but because you're doing it incorrectly. Aaron --> Request you to update your answer and have the upload work via a Shared Access Signature.